# Get value from a promise near_sdk

Tags: promise, nearprotocol

I'm having a function that return a promise expected to return a u128 value from another contract. How can I get this value from this promise?
Here is my codes:
[image]
[image]

I tried async await in future/rust but it didn't work

Comment: Please provide code in code blocks not as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is baked into the `call_result` variable you have there. The promise will be scheduled after `query_staked_amount` finishes and then once the promise finishes executing, the callback `query_staked_amount_callback` is invoked.

In this callback, the result of the original promise (`get_staked_amount`) will be available in that variable you have `call_result`.

Hope that answers your question.